# How can i get updated record from mysql in a PyQt Window with Python

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5, mysql-python

In a QLineEdit When i type some text(name) which exists in database table, The code below works and it provides me the unique id of that text

But if i update or add new name in database (through a different window OR workbench) the Select Query does not work for that updated name and does not provide the unique id until i relaunch exe. The Select Query must work every time whenever text is changed in QLineEdit.

```
cur = db() #MySQLdb

class My_Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("test.ui", self)
        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.findid)

    def findid(self, txt):
        if txt:
            name_txt = (self.lineEdit.text(),)
            select_id = f"SELECT id from accounts WHERE name = %s"
            cur.execute(select_id , name_txt)
            name_id = cur.fetchone()
            if name_id:
                print(name_id[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    The_Window = My_Window()
    The_Window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: *But if I update or add a new name in database* -- Do you mean, from a different process?

Comment: Yes, from a different pyqt window. Even i updated the record using workbench. But this window does not get the id of that new/updated name

Comment: What Mysql connector are you using?  If the change has been committed, then it should be visible as soon as you requery.

Comment: I am using Mysqldb. Yes, the updated name shows up in the other window. But this window does not show the uodated name's id

Comment: You do understand (I think you do) that the window won't update automatically.  You'll have to change the line edit control to get a requery.

Comment: Yes i understand window does not update automatically thats why i tried the SELECT ID query in QLineEdit's textChanged signal
Everytine textChanged signal emits, the SELECT query in the function must check if this name exists in database, database already have been uodated before this query runs. Am i doing it the wrong way? I am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same cursor instance cur for each query. When a cursor is created, it keeps track of its state, including the current position in the result set.
So, if you execute a query and fetch some rows, and then execute another query on the same cursor, it will continue from where it left off.

You can try this:

1. Remove the first line `cur = db()`
2. Create and close cursor inside `findid`

For example:

```
def findid(self, txt):
    if txt:
        name_txt = (self.lineEdit.text(),)
        select_id = "SELECT id from accounts WHERE name = %s"
        cur = db()  # Create cursor
        cur.execute(select_id, name_txt)
        name_id = cur.fetchone()
        if name_id:
            print(name_id[0])
        cur.close()  # Close the cursor
```

Comment: Exactly... Thanks Qri... It solved the issue :)